# How to put a time limit on a method in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my player to give a speed boost for a few seconds. When it collects 4 items (paintCount = 4), the player gets a movement speed boost for a short period of time.
How do I code this time that my player moves faster?

I'm using c# and Unity.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PowerUp : MonoBehaviour
{
  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
  {
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
      Paintser.SpeedUp();
      Destroy(this.gameObject);
      Paintser.paintCount++;
    }
  }
}



using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Paintser : PowerUp
{

  public static int paintCount = 0;
  public int speedBoostTime = 3;

  public static void SpeedUp()
  {
    if (paintCount == 4)
    {

      SimplePlayer0.speed = SimplePlayer0.speed * 2;

      Paintser.paintCount = Paintser.paintCount = 0;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Unity exactly, but the general idea is usually to have a `TimeSpan timeLeft` on the power up. Each update cycle, you subtract the elapsed time since the last update cycle from `timeLeft`. When `timeLeft` reaches 0, the power up ends.

Comment: Where does the player gets its speed? Why not make a variable and change that in the SpeedUp() method?

Answer (score 2):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Paintser : PowerUp
{
  public float normalSpeed = 10;
  public static int paintCount = 0;
  public int speedBoostTime = 3;

  public static void SpeedUp(){

      SimplePlayer0.speed = SimplePlayer0.speed * 2;
      Paintser.paintCount = Paintser.paintCount = 0;
      StartCoroutine(duringBoost(speedBoostTime, normalSpeed));
    }

    private static IEnumerator duringBoost(int duration, int newSpeed){
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
       SimplePlayer0.speed = newSpeed;
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but it gives one error for Enumerator: The type or namespace name 'Enumerator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Typo: 'Enumerator' => 'IEnumerator'

Comment: Now I get this error for StartCoroutine("duringBoost"); : An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(string)'.

Comment: That means that StartCoroutine is a Non-Static method, which CANNOT be called in a static method. You have to somehow make the method static, or instantiate an object of the class containing the "StartCoroutine", and all it through the instantiated object.

Comment: I'll try that, but I'm not sure if I'll succeed. I makes things just more cimplicated, not?

Comment: Edited. Try that. Method is now static.

Comment: im willing to bet you didnt set the new public variable via the unity inspector

Answer (score 1):

A general idea should be:

Add this to the script of SimplePlayer0:

```
float speedBoostTime = 0;

void SpeedUp()
{
    speed *= 2;
    speedBoostTime = 3; // seconds
}

void Update()
{
    while ( speedBoostTime > 0 )
    {
        speedBoostTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        if ( speedBoostTime <= 0 ) speed /= 2;
    }
}
```

And modify your code in this way:

```
public class Paintser : PowerUp
{

  public static int paintCount = 0;
  public int speedBoostTime = 3;

  public static void SpeedUp()
  {
    if (paintCount == 4)
    {

      SimplePlayer0.SpeedUp();

      Paintser.paintCount = Paintser.paintCount = 0;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. The code gives one error. I can't acces SpeedUp() due its protection level. So SimplePlayer0.SpeedUp() gives an error.

Comment: make SpeedUp function in SimplePlayer0 public:      public void SpeedUp()

Comment: SimplePlayer0.SpeedUp() still gives an error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SimplePlayer0.SpeedUp()'.

Comment: That means that SimplePlayer0 is not an object but a class. You have two solutions depending on your application architecture: 1.- use an instance of SimplePlayer0 to call SpeedUp. 2.- Make SpeedUp static to call it using SimplePlayer0